# Is there a way to call a dynamic function name in solidity?

Tags: solidity

My code

```
for ( uint256 index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
              string memory name = GetName_v1();
            }
```

`GetName_v1` is a method name and it should be actually a dynamic method name like

`GeName_v${index}`

Is there a way in solidity to achieve such? Or what is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

I think that Mikko's way is the only way even if you want to call other methods of the same contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;


contract Test {
    uint value;
    
    function set(uint n) external{
        value = n;
    }
    
    function get() external view returns(uint) {
        return value;
    }
    
    function callByName(string calldata functionSignature, bytes calldata parameters) external returns(bytes memory) {
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = address(this).delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSelector(
                bytes4(
                    keccak256(bytes(functionSignature))
                ),
                parameters
            )
        );
        require(success, 'Call failed');
        return data;
    }
}
```

Here for example you can call `get()` dynamically calling `callByName('get()', '0x')` instead. Note that the `functionSignature` parameter must include the paramters types e.g. for `set()` it should be `set(uint256)`.
Using this method you must provide the parameters encoding and return data decoding.

I used `delegatecall` since in this case it should be equivalent to `call` but I have seen that this way it needs slightly less gas.

However this solution isn't great for at least two reasons:

- All the functions you want to call dynamically must be `public` or `external`, you could make a bad work around adding a modifier like this:

```
modifier isPrivate() {
    require(msg.sender == address(this), 'This method is private');
    _;
}
```

- The compiler manages really differently externally callable methods (`public`/`external`) from internally callable (`private`/`internal`) and if you want to use this "trick" you must declare your methods externally callable.
  Internally callable methods are managed using the `JUMP` opcode, indeed my first idea was to write an inline assembly snippet to simply jump but unfortunately this is not possible using YUL. For this reason calling methods in this way will make your contract spend more gas since it needs an additional internal transaction.

Comment: won't using `delegatecall()` produce potentially weird effects from using memory where you don't expect it, and not referencing the memory of the contract you're calling when you do expect it...?

Comment: My knowledge about this topic is limited, however I cannot understand what you mean, afaik a `delegatecall` is like a normal call with the difference that the executed code uses the caller's storage. For the uses I've made of it I never noticed any weirdness with the memory.
But I repeat that I might sayng inaccuracies, that snippet was only a quick and cool  proof of concept I wanted to try, I never used it for a real project.

Comment: I'd say be careful, `delegatecall()` makes sense with a proxy format, but you shouldn't use this pattern for calling any given arbitrary contract without looking carefully into exactly how `delegatecall()` works.

Comment: > If state variables are accessed via a low-level delegatecall, the storage layout of the two contracts must align in order for the called contract to correctly access the storage variables of the calling contract by name. This is of course not the case if storage pointers are passed as function arguments as in the case for the high-level libraries. --see warnings here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/units-and-global-variables.html#members-of-address-types

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can manually construct [calldata](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.6.7/internals/layout_in_calldata.html) which contains the input function selector (4 bytes) and then arguments to the function.

Here is a post that [covers the topic](https://medium.com/@houzier.saurav/calling-functions-of-other-contracts-on-solidity-9c80eed05e0f).

Comment: Thanks but that is not actually the solution I am looking for. Infact the dynamic methods all exists within the same contract.

Comment: AFAIK you can call your own contract in similar manner.

Comment: But I dont see function name being dynamic there. Because Test is the function name and its static in the code as bytes memory payload = abi.encodeWithSignature("Test(uint, uint)", 12, 35);
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) = address(addr).call(payload);
require(success);

Comment: You can generate strings dynamically in Solidity. How to do this please read Solidity documentation or open another question, as it is out of scope.

Comment: my intention is not to generate strings dynamically. I already have 10 method names as method1,method2 .... method10. The only dynamic in method name is the integer appended at last i.e method${integer}

Comment: Create an if statement

Answer (score 0):

This is playing with fire, but it can be done:

```
    function execute(address _to, bytes calldata _data)
        public
        payable
        returns (bytes memory)
    {
        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = _to.call{value: msg.value}(_data);
        require(success);
        return returnData;
    }
```

Note that "success" returns true any time there is no error... but there is no checking for whether the end address is a contract, or whether the function you are trying to call exists, etc.

Also, you shouldn't change any state after doing this call. You're asking for reentrancy hacks.

How to generate that `_data` param? Here's how you'd do it in a default hardhat test environment (using ethers js):

```js
  function asExecuteArg(functionName, argTypes, ...args) {  
    let signature = `function ${functionName}(${argTypes})`
    let ABI = [signature];
    let interface = new ethers.utils.Interface(ABI);
    let output = interface.encodeFunctionData(functionName, args);
    return output;
  }

  const AccountForwarder = await ethers.getContractFactory("AccountForwarder");
  contractInstance = await AccountForwarder.deploy();

  const executeArg = asExecuteArg('existingFunction', "uint256", 12);

  await contractInstance.execute(contractAddress, executeArg);
```

`contractAddress` will be the address of the deployed contract that has `existingFunction(uint256 _someArg)` in it.